# Create a bar chart with ordered binary data

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I want to create the chart linked below. I have data that is coded with a binary flag (0 = red, 1 = blue) that is also ordered. For example, the data I would use to hypothetically create the left hand column below looks like the table at the link below

**Table**

[image: Data table]

**Chart**

[image: Chart]

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what data creates the right-hand column in the chart?

Comment: It would look like http://i.imgur.com/UfRqkUi.gif

Comment: OK. So, is it safe to assume I can re-arrange the data table like this: http://imgur.com/iln3A0p

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes. I should have done that myself but just wanted to illustrate a point with the first table.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do this (including the data labels, point colors, etc) without using some VBA/code.  If interested in that approach, let me know. It will be limited to this example of 6 series and 2 columns in the chart.

Comment: I would definitely be interested. I am sure I can figure out how to modify anything you do for the entire data set.

Comment: I modified it to be variable, should allow for more rows/columns. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your data table is arranged like:

[image: Data table]

This should accommodate any number of ranks and any number of columns. Run the macro, and select the range of cells containing ALL the binary flags, like:

[image: Select the binary flag values]

And it will create the chart like:

[image: Chart screenshot]

```
Option Explicit
Sub BuildRankedBinaryChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim ax As Axis
    Dim rngFlag As Range
    Dim xVal As Double
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim s As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim pt As Point

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngFlag = Application.InputBox( _
                "Select the binary flags.", _
                "Binary Flag", Type:=8)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '## Determine what VALUES to use for each point:'
    xVal = 1 / rngFlag.Rows.Count
    ReDim xVals(1 To rngFlag.Columns.Count)
    For c = 1 To rngFlag.Columns.Count
        xVals(c) = xVal
    Next

    '## Add a new chart to the sheet.'
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects.Add(50, 50, 300, 200).Chart
    '## Format the chart:'
    With cht
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked100
        .HasLegend = False
        .Axes(xlPrimary).Delete
        Set ax = .Axes(xlSecondary)
        With ax
            .HasMajorGridlines = False
            .HasMinorGridlines = False
            .Delete
            .ReversePlotOrder = True
        End With
    End With

    '## Each ROW in the table is a new series.'
    For r = 1 To rngFlag.Rows.Count
        '## Add a new series to the chart'
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            '## Assign the values calculated above'
                .Values = xVals
            '## Apply labels'
                .ApplyDataLabels
            '## Finally, fake out the labels and apply the color to each point.'
            For p = 1 To .Points.Count
                With .Points(p)
                    If rngFlag.Rows(r).Cells(1, p).Value = 1 Then
                        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
                        .DataLabel.Text = 1
                    Else:
                        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
                        .DataLabel.Text = 0
                    End If
                    '## Use a white font which is more legible on the dark fill colors '
                    .DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
                End With
            Next
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Each data point in the chart will be the same size (I think that is what you wanted from the screen shots).  This size is calculated by dividing 1 by the number of rows in your table, e.g., for 6 rows it would be `0.166666667`, so that the stacked columns all add to 100%.

The value labels are overridden, and assigned to be the flag value of 1 or 0.

The colors are red or blue, based on the value of 1 or 0.  I made the font color white so it will be more legible against the blue & red fills.

Answer (score 0):

The result below can be achieved with charts (no VBA) using, perhaps counter intuitively, a stacked  bar chart (and adjusting umpteen other settings from the defaults!):

[image: SO16797200 first example]

*Edit in response to comment requesting further details*

Some (maybe not all!) the adjustments likely to be required to default settings:

**Borders**
Format Data Series should be set to Border Color Solid Line (Color may default to Black, Transparency to 0%) and Border Styles to about 3 pt (or equivalent, rest may be default) for both `Binary Flag` and `Series1`.

**Colours**
Format Data Series for `Series1` data points should be Fill, Solid Fill, Color: Red and Transparency 0% (`Binary Flag` may default to blue and not require adjustment).

**Format Axis**
For X Axis, Axis Options all set to Fixed, with values Minimum: 0, Maximum: 1, Major: 1, Minor: 1 and Major tick mark type:, Minor tick mark type: and Axis labels: all set to None. Vertical axis crosses: set to about 0.75.

For Y Axis, Line Color set to No line.

**Legend**
Delete.

**Series Options**
Set to Series Overlap Separated 100%, Gap Width No Gap (0%) with Plot Series On defaulting to Primary Axis.

**Size**
Drag the right chart border to the left to suit.

---

*Alternative*

Though perhaps easier with conditional formatting (provided Rank sort order is reversed):

[image: SO16797200second example]

Comment: So what are the adjustments from the defaults that you have to make?